# Outputting Errors to User

Tags: c#, validation

I currently am making a small application where a user will enter their ID which needs to be in a certain format.  When entered in the wrong format, different output errors are produced.

I currently output errors like this:

```
public void errorLogger(string error)
        {
            errors += error + Environment.NewLine + "<br>";
        }
```

I have read that using `+=` is not a great operator to use. Alternatively I have thought this may be better:

```
public void errorLogger(string key, string err)
        {
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(err))
            output.Add(key, err);
        }
```

but then I basically do the same thing later:

```
    string keys = "";
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in core.errorLogger())
    {
        keys += entry.Key + ":       " + entry.Value + "<br>";
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way to output errors?  The output is injected under the submit button into:

```
errorSpan.InnerHtml = (keys);
```

This is what I ended up using going off of Charles' response to AWinkle

```
public void logError(string err, string desc)
                {
                    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(desc))
                        errors.AppendFormat("{0,10}:&nbsp;{1}<br>", err, desc);
                }
public string getErrors()
            {
                return errors.ToString();
            }
```

Then :

```
errorspan.InnerHtml = (core.getErrors());
```

Comment: Please put your full code or at least the parts needed to in this code snippet, errors and output for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `StringBuilder` class will typically be better for looped string building.

```
string keys = "";
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in core.errorLogger())
{
    keys += entry.Key + ":       " + entry.Value + "<br>";
}
```

turns into

```
StringBuilder keys = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in core.errorLogger())
{
    keys.AppendFormat("{0}:&nbsp;{1}<br>", entry.Key, entry.Value);
}
```

Then you take `errorSpan.InnerHtml = (keys);` and change it to `errorSpan.InnerHtml = (keys.ToString());`

Alternatively, you could use this to replace the dictionary as CharlesNRice suggests.

```
StringBuilder keys = new StringBuilder();

 public void errorLogger(string key, string err)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(err))
        keys.AppendFormat("{0}:&nbsp;{1}<br>", key,err);
    }
```

Comment: In this situation `StringBuilder` for a few rare error messages is likely to be a premature optimization (if it is an optimization at all).

Comment: Why have the dictionary in the first place if you are going to use string builder and have a method to format the string and add to the string builder right away.

Comment: @CharlesNRice I added an alternative version based on your comment. You make a valid point, that a dictionary might be overkill/under-optimized (it probably is).

Answer (score 4):

This answer is another way of achieving the same. I am not claiming that this is the cleanest or most performant way but it certainly works.

### `List<string>`

When you're using this method to store all the error messages, you can use the [**Enumerable.Aggregate<TSource>**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var errors = new List<string>();

errors.Add("This is error message 1.");
errors.Add("Another error!");

var message = errors.Aggregate((c, n) => c + Environment.NewLine + n);
```

Outputted, `message` will now have following value:

> This is error message 1.
>
> Another error!

You can also look into the [**String.Join**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The message is built up like this:

```
var message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);
```

This will create the same output.

### `Dictionary<int, string>`

In a situation where you store an integer as a key and the message as a string in a `Dictionary<int, string>`, you can also the **String.Join** method:

```
var errors = new Dictionary<int, string>();

errors.Add(1, "This is error message 1.");
errors.Add(2, "Another error!");

var message = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors.Select(x => String.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Key, x.Value)));
```

The result looks like this:

> 1: This is error message 1.
>
> 2: Another error!

Comment: I'm a really big fan of this because everyone needs to use Linq and Lambda more.